# Update запрос на обновление нескольких записей из массива

Tags: php, mysqli, update

Помогите с запросом.

```
$sql = "SELECT `first_name`, 
               `uidvk`, 
               `rot` 
          FROM `rotation` 
         WHERE `first_name` = 'Леонид'"

$Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, $sql);

$array = array();

while($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query) ){
    $array[] = $Row;
}
```

Вот у нас есть массив с Леонидами.

Мне нужно сделать апдейт всем Леонидам.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `rotation` 
           SET `date` = NOW(), 
               `trah` = '$_SESSION[USER_UIDVK]' 
          WHERE ... "; // Тут нужно как-то сделать, чтобы апдейт
                       // сделался по Леонидам из массива.

mysqli_query($CONNECT, $sql);
```

Что-то типа: *WHERE `first_name` = 'Леонид'* - не устраивает. Ибо задача в том, чтоб ориентировка шла по людям именно из массива. Вот не знаю пока как это сделать.

Comment: Может стоит взять `id` всех выбранных записей с леонидами а потом сделать `UPDATE` используя `IN` ?

Comment: а что в этом массиве уникальное? `uidvk`?

Comment: хотя айди в моём случае не будет, но покажите пожалуйста пример.

Comment: да, юайди уникально. и на самом деле будет извлекаться массив всех записей, потом будет запрос к апи, после которого в массиве останутся только лишь подходящие уюайдивк

Comment: Что такое "ориентировка по людям"? Я смотрю на ваши запросы и не понимиаю, что именно вы хотите сделать. Сортитровки у вас нет, да она и не поможет - NOW() запишет одинаковое время всем Леонидам независимо от порядка.

Comment: Другие поняли и ответили

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае, как я понимаю, вместо `id` будут `uidvk`. Так как они уникальны.

Есть минимум два способа сделать выборку.

1) Сделать массив с идентификаторами, на основе первой выборки. И по ним сделать `UPDATE`
`$array` - массив с результатом выборки `SELECT`

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    array_push($ids, $item['uidvk']);
}

mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `rotation` SET `date` = NOW(), `trah` = '$_SESSION[USER_UIDVK]' WHERE `uidvk` IN (". implode(',', $ids) .")");
```

`implode` — Объединяет элементы массива в строку используя заданный разделитель. В моем случае это запятая

2) Сделать доп. выборку данных идентификаторов используя `GROUP_CONCAT` и по результату сделать `UPDATE`

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(uidvk) AS ids  FROM`rotation`WHERE`first_name`= 'Леонид'`

результатом (`$ids`) будет строка, типа `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`
На её основе делаем запрос

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `rotation` SET `date` = NOW(), `trah` = '$_SESSION[USER_UIDVK]' WHERE `uidvk` IN (". $ids .")");
```

3) Еще каки-либо способы

Хотя в таком случае, так же обновятся записи у всех леонидов))
Возможно вы имели в виду, что хотите обновить записи по массиву `$_SESSION[USER_UIDVK]`.

Если так, то можно в `UPDATE` воспользоваться лишь `implode` и `$_SESSION[USER_UIDVK]` соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Как всегда, отвечатели поголовно ничего не слышали про SQL инъекции.

```
$sql = "UPDATE rotation SET date = NOW(), `trah` = ?  WHERE uidvk = ?";
$stmt = $CONNECT->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_SESSION['USER_UIDVK'], $row['uidvk']);
foreach ($array as $row)
{
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Кто сказал? Просто смысл вопроса в другом.... Кстати с подготовленными выражениями также можно `IN` использовать, так что ваш цикл немного лишний

Comment: А при чем тут инъекции. Я думал они делаются тогда, когда через пост или гет передаются данные, и потом эти данные идут в запросе. Думал защита от sql инъекций кроется в обработке данных, все данные с пост, гет или кук я обрабатываю перед занесением в базу спец. функцией. А тут как вызывается инъекция не понимаю. Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row['uidvk'];
}
```

Используйте PHP функцию [implode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php), а в SQL запросе **IN**

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `rotation` SET `date` = NOW(), `trah` = '$_SESSION[USER_UIDVK]' WHERE `uidvk` IN (" . implode(',', $array) . ")");
```

Comment: Почему минусовали. Я сделал именно так, работает.

Comment: @MrCoder если вам помог ответ - отметьте его как принятым